# Remove table row using Jquery from checkbox values

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have created an array from an HTML form containing the checkbox values.

I was wondering if it is possible to pass the selected checkbox values to jquery to use the Jquery code $('tr#myTableRow').remove(); for each array value that was posted by the form?

Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
<form name="deletePost" id="deletePost" action="" method="post"> 
    <input class="checkBox" type="checkbox" id="idArray" name="idArray[]" value="1" />
    <input class="checkBox" type="checkbox" id="idArray" name="idArray[]" value="2" />
    <input class="formButtonDelete" type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>

$ids = $_POST['idArray'];
if(!empty($ids))
{
    foreach($ids as $id)
   {
      $sql = "DELETE FROM news WHERE id='$id'";
     mysql_query($sql);
   }
echo 'Posts Deleted - Please refesh page..';
}
```

I would like to use Jquery to remove the table rows that have the ids of the input values..

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('input[name=submit]').click(function(){
    $('#deletePost input:checkbox').each(function(){
        if(this.checked){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I added `return false;` so you can see the input removed before submission, you may remove it to let the form submit

See this http://jsfiddle.net/F5Nth/

Comment: This just deletes the checkbox it self, I need it to delete the whole table row with the checkbox value id, lke so: <tr id="1"></tr> - $('#1').remove(); - like a for each loop in jquery to delete each row selected

Comment: I have modified this code and it works however I now have a new problem, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434861/jquery-need-to-post-data-after-removing-table-row